# kafka-configs.sh can't find kafka.admin.ConfigCommand

Tags: apache-kafka

I've downloaded Kafka bash script on https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=/kafka/2.2.0/kafka_2.12-2.2.0.tgz

When I run `./kafka_2.12-2.2.0/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper localhost:12181 --entity-type topics --entity-name challenges --alter --add-config cleanup.policy=compact,segment.bytes=1000000,segment.ms=60000`.

Or just `./kafka_2.12-2.2.0/bin/kafka-configs.sh`

I always have an error

> "Can't find or load kafka.admin.ConfigCommand"

.

And I have already tried to re-download and to test with `kafka_2.12-2.3.0.tgz`

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10 and use Git bash to run script

Comment: did you try using  `bin/windows/kafka-configs.bat` ?

Comment: Yes but I have 'line is to long' error

Comment: What is the full path of the folder? Are there spaces in it?